# Override OnCancel button in MFC/Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a model dialog.  I overrided OnCancel function to stop unexpected exiting by pressing ESC button.  But this caused a new problem.  I can't close the application by using close (x) button.  My implementation of function is:

```
void MyDlg::OnCancel()
{
}
```

Comment: OnCancel is called by pressing the x button or by pressing escape, and there's no way to tell within the function.  You could add a message dialog to ask if the user is sure they want to quit, or look at trapping the escape key-press specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing a dialog effectively cancels it. Since you have disabled close in your OnCancel handler, then nothing will happen.

To disable ESC only, you need to preprocess the keyboard messages:

```
BOOL CYourDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
   switch ( pMsg->message )
   {
       case WM_KEYDOWN:

           switch( pMsg->wParam )
           {
               case VK_ESCAPE:
               case VK_CANCEL: return true;
           }
           break;
   }

   return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution.  It's works fine... But I have an another question how to stop exiting while pressing ESC button ?

Comment: I think it's better to do is in another way: "typedef CDialog base_class", then call "base_class::OnCancel();" instead of using VC-specific __super keyword.

Comment: @krish Just call base OnCancel() only then you need to exit dialog. I.e. use "if" statement.

Comment: @Raxillan I go with GazTheDestroyer's solution, thank you for answer